# POST data from PHP and GET data in java servlet

Tags: java, php, servlets

is there any method that I can retrieve data (eg, username and password) from PHP to a Java servlet? Thanks

Comment: You already asked that no? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595660/send-data-from-php-to-java-application

Answer (score 1):

Create a POST request in PHP:

Use cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com:8080/my-servlet/');
$data = '...' # the data you want to send

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

A better, more concise approach, using [pecl_http](http://pecl.php.net/pecl_http):

```
$response = http_post_data('http://www.example.com:8080/my-servlet/', $data);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. meanwhile i also need to GET that data by using java servlet. do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: GET can be passed through URL, so just redirect to: http://www.example.com:8080/my-servlet/?var=value&var2=value2

Answer (score 0):

POST and GET pretty much do not depend on the language being used, so if I understand your question correctly, you can use either $_POST['var'] in PHP or request.getParameter("var") in Java on the page that receives the POST data.

Comment: oh, really? but both are on different host...i thought i need some http connection to retrieve the POST data?

Comment: There are two possible scenarios here: either the POST data is sent from a form directly to a PHP or Java page (then you can simple access it like I said), or the POST data is sent from a form to a PHP page, and from there you want to send it to a Java page--in that case you need to use CURL and someone else has already shown that :)